# ToString() in a Webservice Class

Tags: c#, web-services, tostring

I have implemented a `ToString()` override method for my class in my Webservice and I return a `List<myObject>()` in a function in a consumer. If I do a `.ToString()` it returns object Type. How do I tackle this in C#?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you saying you have a .ToString() method that does not return a string? Rename it.

Comment: No, it returns object type if I use it in .aspx page .

Comment: I think he's saying that the override doesn't seem to be working correctly when he calls the toString() method on the base class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When passing objects back & forth in a webservice, it's just passing an XML representations of the public properties of that object.  Any methods, overridden or not, do not come with it.

I would recommend making a StringRepresentation property that calls ToString()

```
public string StringRepresentation
{
    get { return this.ToString(); }
    set { /* Do Nothing, but there has to be a set */ }
}
```

Comment: Basically, you can only pass strings over a webservice.  So, it compiles your object into XML and passes the XML instead of the actual object.